# C++: Building a Matrix Class

Tags: matrix, computer-science

I know they are out there, but I think that I can learn a lot by creating my own. I do not want to get too convoluted with optimizing this thing, but I was hoping some folks could offer some input.

I am narrowing the scope of this project so that the goal is to end up with a Matrix class that could be used for Gaussian elimination and matrix addition and multiplication for now.

My outline is as follows:

```
Code:
1. Class name: Matrix

2. Uses <vector> as a building block.

3. Constructors should consider:
  a. Data Type
  b. Size of Matrix to be created 

4. Member functions:
  a. row swapping
  b. row multiply by non zero, real, constant
  c. add multiple of one row to another row 
  d. get/set Element
  e. augment (to append column of constants for solving systems)
  f. gauss solve

5. Properties:
  a. is singular
  b. is zero
  c. is square
```

I am sure there is much to consider, but I am just looking for a starting point.

Do you see any problems with using vector as my building block? Any other elementary member functions/properties you would suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good start. I would start building and testing with what you have...then make changes when need.

Once you start witting code and test you will see what needs to change, or needs to be added.

I would start with an 2x2 Matrix to start with then move to bigger ones.